# Printing Multiple JTable in a PDF using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to print two `JTable`  in a PDF file,  here is what I tried but is printing only the headers of the column, please how will I add the content of the table.

```
try{
 Document document = new Document();
 PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("transcript.pdf"));
 document.open();
 document.add(new Paragraph("UNIVERSITY  OF  MAIDUGURI"));
 document.add(new Paragraph("======================================================================="));
 PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(partITable.getColumnCount());
 PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(partITable2.getColumnCount());
 table1.setSpacingAfter(10);
 table1.setSpacingBefore(5);

 for(int i=0;i<partITable.getColumnCount();i++){
 table1.addCell(partITable.getColumnName(i));
 }
 for(int rows=0;rows<partITable.getRowCount()-1;rows++){
     for(int cols=0;cols<partITable.getColumnCount();cols++){
     table1.addCell(partITable.getModel().getValueAt(rows,cols).toString());
     }

 }
 for(int i=0;i<partITable2.getColumnCount();i++){
 table2.addCell(partITable2.getColumnName(i));
 }
 for(int rows=0;rows<partITable2.getRowCount()-1;rows++){
     for(int cols=0;cols<partITable2.getColumnCount();cols++){
     table2.addCell(partITable2.getModel().getValueAt(rows,cols).toString());
     }

 }
 document.add(table1);
 document.add(table2);

 document.close();
 }
 catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic error. I guess that you have following situation: `partITable.getRowCount() = partITable2.getRowCount() = 1`. Because you set the upper bound to `partITable.getRowCount() - 1 = 0`, the condition of the for loop returns `false`, which implies that the body of the for loop will be never executed.

Summarized you have to set the upper bound to `partITable.getRowCount()`